# Why can I not access bitmap data of FLV video coming from Amazon S3?

Tags: actionscript-2, amazon-s3, cross-domain, flv, bitmapdata

I have a video player that loads progressive flv video from a server and applies a reflection to it. I do this by creating a bitmapData object and then drawing the video to it. This worked absolutely fine until we moved our content from testing server to Amazon S3. Now there is no reflection.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and even suggest a solution?

p.s. i am using Flash 8 AS2.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most likely has to do with Flash player's security restrictions and domains. If you aren't getting any errors, try installing the debug version of the player and see what comes up.

Also take a look to [Handling Crossdomain.xml and 302 Redirects Using NetStream](http://jessewarden.com/2009/03/handling-crossdomainxml-and-302-redirects-using-netstream.html) for background info.

HTH

Juan

Comment: Yep thanks, I found this info after a further bit of googling... hmph I agree with one of the commenters that Adobe surely have to address this problem as we see more and more flash in the cloud!